# How can I add a whitespace to a string in erb?

Tags: html, ruby, erb

I'm displaying a link as a string in erb:

```
<%= link_to (@teacher.id + 1).to_s, "#" %>
```

How can I add one space at the beginning?
If I do this: `" " + (@teacher.id + 1).to_s`, the space is ignored, and if I do this: `"&nbsp" + (@teacher.id + 1).to_s` or this: `'&nbsp' + (@teacher.id + 1).to_s`, it just interprets "&nbsp" as a five-character string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "&nbsp;#{@teacher.id + 1}".html_safe, "#" %>
```

Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe